# Can't delete data after 10 entries in AJAX, JQuery and javascript/php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have 10 rows with data inserted and I'm able to delete any of those, but after I insert from 11th row onwards I can't delete any of the rows after the 10th.

EDIT (I CAN'T DELETE ANYTHING WHEN THE RESPONSIVE FORM IS SHOWING)

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#list').dataTable({
                    responsive: true
                });
            $('.delete_piece').click(function(){
            _conf("Are you sure to delete this piece?","delete_piece",[$(this).attr('data-id')])
            })
            })
            function delete_piece($id){
                start_load()
                $.ajax({
                    url:'ajax.php?action=delete_piece',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{id:$id},
                    success:function(resp){
                        if(resp==1){
                            alert_toast("Data successfully deleted",'success')
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                location.reload()
                            },1500)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
```

DELETE FUNCTION AJAX

```
if($action == "delete_piece"){
$delsete = $crud->delete_piece();
if($delsete)
    echo $delsete;
}
```

DELETE FUNCTION FOR THE ADMIN (ME)

```
    function delete_piece(){
     extract($_POST);
     $delete = $this->db->query("DELETE FROM mro_inventory where id = ".$id);
     if($delete){
        return 1;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Its unclear what you mean. Are there new rows being added after the page loads that don't react to your click event? Also, your method for executing SQL is extremely unsecure and could be disastrous to your DB

Comment: Thank you for attenting but it could be nice if you explain me what is the especific disastroud of the method and what you recommed to improve to the DB.

Comment: your code is wide open to SQL injection attack. Never use variables directly in the sql, use `prepared statements`

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I'm still learning about it, and new from the programming world, this is just a test of future web app, but I want to make it more safety as good as possible.. and I have some questions like the above, I'm still stuck in the issue that It doesn't let me do a delete for a row after the 10th row, It would be awesome if you help me with this. Regards!!!!

Comment: The primary issue you are reporting is related to dynamically created items. Sicne they are added after the first 10, the `click` event is not bound to them. To address this, I would advise using the `.on()` to bind the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function delete_piece($id) {
    start_load()
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax.php?action=delete_piece',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        id: $id
      },
      success: function(resp) {
        if (resp == 1) {
          alert_toast("Data successfully deleted", 'success')
          setTimeout(function() {
            location.reload()
          }, 1500);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $('#list').dataTable({
    responsive: true
  });
  
  $('tbody').on("click", ".delete_piece", function(e) {
    _conf("Are you sure to delete this piece?", "delete_piece", [$(this).attr('data-id')])
  });
});
```

This uses the `.on()` method to delegate the click event to a class.

> **Delegated event handlers** have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated event handlers to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

See more: https://api.jquery.com/on/

It was not clear from your post what the HTML structure looks like; yet, you are using DataTables, so I know there should be a Table Body element that should be present.

Comment: @Antonio glad I could help. When your Rep goes up, you can also Upvote answers that you find helpful.

Comment: I got another error related about "HTML : Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick" when I use your code, it shows me that in the console

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Oh I already solved the issue, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solved the problem!!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#list').dataTable({
    responsive: true
  });
  $('tbody').on("click", ".delete_piece", function() {
    _conf("Are you sure to delete this piece?","delete_piece",[$(this).attr('data-id')])
  })
})
function delete_piece($id){
  start_load()
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php?action=delete_piece',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      id:$id
    },
    success: function(resp) {
      if (resp == 1) {
        alert_toast("Data successfully deleted",'success')
        setTimeout(function() {
          location.reload()
        }, 1500)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.